# Npm installation failed due to MaxListenersExceededWarning. 11 close listener added to [TLSSocket]

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am setting up github repo [expensify/App] on my local machine and while installing npm packages, i am getting these errors in my console log

```
(node:17180) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\Projects\\ExpensifyApp\\node_modules\\@storybook\\addon-toolbars',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Projects\ExpensifyApp\node_modules\@storybook\addon-toolbars\node_modules\@storybook'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\Projects\\ExpensifyApp\\node_modules\\@storybook\\addon-toolbars\\node_modules\\@storybook'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ],
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\Projects\\ExpensifyApp\\node_modules',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Projects\ExpensifyApp\node_modules\@oguzhnatly\react-native-image-manipulator\Example\ios\Example'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\Projects\\ExpensifyApp\\node_modules\\@oguzhnatly\\react-native-image-manipulator\\Example\\ios\\Example'   
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ],
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\Projects\\ExpensifyApp\\node_modules\\@oguzhnatly',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Projects\ExpensifyApp\node_modules\@oguzhnatly\react-native-image-manipulator\Example\android\app\src\main\res'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\Projects\\ExpensifyApp\\node_modules\\@oguzhnatly\\react-native-image-manipulator\\Example\\android\\app\\src\\main\\res'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ]
npm WARN cleanup ]
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/zwitch/-/zwitch-1.0.5.tgz failed, reason: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.
```

My internet connection is good, so there is no problem in my connection, this is a company repo and i'm interested for open source contribution, is there is any safety protocaol set by the company that causing these errors ?

Answer (score 1):

Solved This Problem :-

I uninstalled my node and then installed nvm to install the proper version of the node also I have cleared the .npmrc file (c/users/hp/.npmrc). open this file in a text editor with administrative permission, delete everything, and save.